# Footnote into a \twocolumn expression

Tags: numbering, footnotes, two-column

I have a paper that uses the `article` document class, in `twocolumn` mode. The title and the author are set within a `\twocolumn[...]` command. Now I need to put a footnote after the name of the first author, so that a small "1" appears next to it and the footnote (containing the e-mail of the first author) must go at the bottom of the page.

The problem is that I've discovered that `\footnote`, within `\twocolumn`, makes the small "1" appear right after the name of the first author (but not so close to it, and this is not good) but I don't find the footnote at the bottom of the page.

How can I perform this task?

As an example I put here below a small piece of code that demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[{\centering \LARGE \textbf{Test\footnote{Test title 
      footnote} Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test \bigskip}}]

    Test\footnote{test text footnote} Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
    Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
    Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
    Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
    Test Test Test Test Test Test 
\end{document}
```

As you could verify, the first footnote does not appear, while the footnote into the text, appears, and with the number 2.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\footnotemark` within the float and then `\footnotetext` at some point on the first page but outside the float. Alternatively if you used `\thanks` it is defined (in two column mode) to do exactly that. It makes a mark at the point it is used, but saves the text so that `\maketitle` first sets the title texts in a 2 column float and then executes all the saved `\footnotetext` commands from `\thanks`.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the [tablefootnote](http://ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote) package, which also takes care of the right hyperlinking, if the [hyperref](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package is used:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\spewnotes}{%
\tfn@tablefootnoteprintout%
\global\let\tfn@tablefootnoteprintout\relax%
\gdef\tfn@fnt{0}%
}
\makeatother

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[{\centering \LARGE \textbf{Test\tablefootnote{Test title 
      footnote} Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test \bigskip}}]
\spewnotes

    Test\footnote{test text footnote} Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
    Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
    Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
    Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
    Test Test Test Test Test Test 
\end{document}
```

You just need to make sure that there is no page break between '\footnote{...}' and \spewnotes, otherwise the spewed footnotes end at the second page.